# Alternative definition of refinement

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Are the following interchangable ways of defining the definition of refinement of a partition on a set?

1. $P$ is a refinement of $S$ if and only if both sets are partitions of a set $U$ and every $P$-cell is included in a $S$-cell. (this implies that for every $S$-cell, there is a $P$-cell included in it, while the converse is false).
2. $P$ is a refinement of $S$ if and only if both sets are partitions and every $S$-cell is a union of $P$-cells.

I do not think they are actually interchangable.
2 does not imply 1, in fact we could have {a,b,c,d} as a partition and {x,y} as a partition in which x is the union of a with b and y is the union of a with c, but d is not included in any member of {x,y}.

Would an equivalent way to express 2 be:

3. $P$ is a refinement of $S$ if and only if both sets are partitions of a set $U$ and every $S$-cell includes a $P$-cell?

From 2 to 3 it is clear, but how can I prove that from 3 it follows that every $S$-cell is the union of some $P$-cells?

Answer (score 1):

If $x=a\cup b$ and $y=a\cup c$, then $\{x,y\}$ isn’t a partition of anything unless $a=\varnothing$, in which case $\{a,b,c,d\}$ isn’t a partition of anything: the members of a partition must be pairwise disjoint and non-empty.

Assuming that $P$ and $S$ are both partitions of the same set $U$, $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equivalent. That $(2)$ implies $(1)$ is clear, so assume $(1)$, i.e., that for each $p\in P$ there is an $s_p\in S$ such that $p\subseteq s_p$.

First observe that $s_p$ is unique: if $s,s'\in S$, $p\subseteq s$, and $p\subseteq s'$, then $s\cap s'\ne\varnothing$, so $s=s'$. Next, for each $s\in S$ there is at least one $p\in P$ such that $s=s_p$: if not, $U=\bigcup P\subseteq U\setminus s\subsetneqq U$, which is absurd. For each $s\in S$ let $$P_s=\{p\in P:s_p=s\}\,;$$ we just saw that $P_s\ne\varnothing$, and I claim that in fact $s=\bigcup P_s$, so that every member of $S$ is indeed a union of members of $P$.

To see this, let $u\in s$. There is some $p\in P$ such that $u\in p$, so $$s_p\cap s\supseteq p\cap s\ne\varnothing\,,$$ and therefore $s=s_p$. But then $u\in p\in P_s$, so $u\in\bigcup P_s$. And $u$ was an arbitrary element of $s$, so $\bigcup P_s\subseteq s\subseteq\bigcup P_s$, i.e., $s=\bigcup P_s$.